# Logical Problem in tkinter. Label won't destroy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a calculator that has many featuresa and in my geometric calculator ive run into a problem and am not able to destroy a label.

```
def geometric_calc_press():
    global bool_

    def formula():
        global bool_, formula_entry
        if bool_:
            formula_entry = Entry(geometric_calc, width=66)
            formula_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1000)
            bool_ = False


        def show_searched_formula():
            global formula_entry, bool_
            try:
                font = tkFont.Font(size=40)
                searched_formula = formula_entry.get()
                area_formulas = ['1/2 ⋅ g ⋅ h', 'g ⋅ h', 'a ⋅ a', 'a ⋅ b', '1/2 ⋅ (a + c) ⋅ h']

                triangle_area = ['triangle', 'area of triangle', 'area of a triangle', 'triangle area',
                                 'Area of triangle',
                                 'Triangle Area', 'Area Of a Triangle', 'triangles area',
                                 'Triangles area', 'what is the area of a triangle', 'trianglearea']
                square_area = ['square', 'area of square', 'area of a square', 'square area', 'Area of square',
                               'Square Area', 'Area Of a Square', 'squares area',
                               'Squares area', 'what is the area of a square', 'squarearea']
                rectangle_area = ['rectangle', 'area of rectangle', 'area of a rectangle', 'rectangle area',
                                  'Area of rectangle',
                                  'Rectangle Area', 'Area Of a Rectangle', 'rectangles area',
                                  'Rectangle area', 'what is the area of a rectangle', 'rectanglearea']
                paralellogram_area = ['paralellogram', 'area of paralellogram', 'area of a paralellogram',
                                      'paralellogram area', 'Area of paralellogram',
                                      'Paralellogram Area', 'Area Of a Paralellogram', 'paralellogram area',
                                      'Paralellogram area', 'what is the area of a Paralellogram', 'paralellogramarea']
                trapezoid_area = ['trapezoid', 'area of trapezoid', 'area of a trapezoid',
                                      'trapezoid area', 'Area of trapezoid',
                                      'Trapezoid Area', 'Area Of a Trapezoid', 'trapezoid area',
                                      'Trapezoid area', 'what is the area of a Trapezoid', 'trapezoidarea']


                if searched_formula in triangle_area:
                    formula = area_formulas[0]
                elif searched_formula in square_area:
                    formula = area_formulas[2]
                elif searched_formula in rectangle_area:
                    formula = area_formulas[3]
                elif searched_formula in paralellogram_area:
                    formula = area_formulas[1]
                elif searched_formula in trapezoid_area:
                    formula = area_formulas[4]

                space = Label(geometric_calc, text='', bg='black').grid(row=4, column=0)
                space2 = Label(geometric_calc, text='', bg='black').grid(row=5, column=0)
                space3 = Label(geometric_calc, text='', bg='black').grid(row=6, column=0)
                space4 = Label(geometric_calc, text='', bg='black').grid(row=7, column=0)
                space5 = Label(geometric_calc, text='', bg='black').grid(row=8, column=0)
                space6 = Label(geometric_calc, text='', bg='black').grid(row=9, column=0)
                show_formula = Label(geometric_calc, text=formula, bg='black', fg='lime', font=font)
                show_formula.grid(row=10, column=0, columnspan=1000)

            except UnboundLocalError:
                pass

        def close():
            global bool_, formula_entry, close, search_
            bool_ = True
            formula_entry.destroy()
            close_.destroy()
            search.destroy()
            formula_finder.config(state='normal')

        if not bool_:
            close_ = Button(geometric_calc, text='Close', command=close, bg='black', fg='lime', highlightcolor="lime",
                            highlightbackground="lime",
                            highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=80, pady=20)
            close_.grid(row=3, column=0)

            search = Button(geometric_calc, text='Search', command=show_searched_formula, bg='black', fg='lime',
                            highlightcolor="lime", highlightbackground="lime",
                            highlightthickness=2, relief=SOLID, default='active', padx=77, pady=20)
            search.grid(row=2, column=0)
            formula_finder.config(state='disabled')
```

I tried to do label.destroy in a not bool_ if statement but it didnt work. Suggestions??? And when i put show_formula.destroy in the close function it says show_formula is not defined.

Comment: nested functions are rarely the right solution, and nesting two deep I would argue is never the right solution. What do you think you're accomplishing by doing that?

Comment: i did it to avoid name errors. Im quite new to pythons tkinter (and python overall) and it was the best solution

Comment: to fix problem ` is not defined.` you could create all variable at start as global variables with default value `None` and later check `if variable is not None: variable.destroy()`

Comment: maybe you assigned new `Label` to variable so now you don't have access to old `Label` and you can't destroy it. OR maybe you assigned label to local variable and you try to destroy using global variable with the same name.

Comment: I dont't see `label.destroy` in your code. And you should always add FULL error message (Traceback) in question - there are many useful information. And you shouldn't do `except UnboundLocalError: pass` - at least when you still create code. It may gives you important error message but you don't know it because you hide it - you shoud display some message or `except UnboundLocalError as ex: print(ex)`